# How to display image for particular time in a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to created a video from the sequence of images. But i have to display each image with different numbers of seconds. How to do this with FFMPEG.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

There are some hints in the [FFmpeg wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images). This one example (second-to-last in the wiki) in particular is likely suitable for your needs:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i img.png -c:v libx264 -t 30 out.mp4
```

where the number after `-t` (30 in the example) is the duration of the video in seconds.

Simply execute that command several times like this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i intro.png -c:v libx264 -t 5 out1.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i someimage.png -c:v libx264 -t 15 out2.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i someotherimage.png -c:v libx264 -t 25 out3.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i outro.png -c:v libx264 -t 10 out4.mp4
```

And then merge the resulting videos (if you want):

1. Create a text file (example: `videos.txt`) where the video filenames are listed.

   `file 'out1.mp4'` 
   `file 'out2.mp4'` 
   `file 'out3.mp4'` 
   `file 'out4.mp4'`
2. Run this command (change filenames if needed)

   `ffmpeg -f concat -i videos.txt -c copy final_video.mp4`

More information about video merging (concatenation) can be found in the [wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files).

Comment: is this the best way to do this ?

Comment: You can avoid creating the list of files to concatenate. In fact, you could avoid creating temporary files altogether, using named pipes. Both is, concisely, explained here:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: @MageProspero No, it's not, check out my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `ffmpeg` includes a section on exactly this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow

Here is an example:

Example content of `input.txt`:

```
file '/path/to/dog.png'
duration 5
file '/path/to/cat.png'
duration 1
file '/path/to/rat.png'
duration 3
file '/path/to/tapeworm.png'
duration 2
file '/path/to/tapeworm.png'
```

Then run:

`ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p -framerate 30 output.mp4`